# CSS linking file not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a lot of CSS files linked, all files work except one file, which is embedded like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/MY_offline_name_name.css">
```

This works in all browsers, except Internet Explorer <= 9. If I embed the CSS inside a `style` tag, though, everything works fine. What could be the reason this is happening?

Comment: So it does work on other browsers?

Comment: It can't be a 404, so it must be an error in your stylesheet which makes Internet Explorer ignore the declarations inside the file.

Comment: but when i embedded the css inside the file or inside the style attr its work perfectly !

Comment: also i create new file with same name nothing change !

Comment: Check the spelling of your css file exactly matches the filename in the style tag. You're using a couple of capital letters there - it's generally considered bad practice to use capital letters in filenames. Check that that file is definitely in the 'css' directory. Check that your html page is on the same directory level as your 'css' directory. Check you have added a doctype to your html page. Check the validity of your css as IE can generally be stricter that other browsers. Also close the tag by adding a '/' before the closing bracket.

Comment: @shox, a demo would be great.

Comment: @Billy i guess this won't be causing the error. @ shox Check if the file is encoded as utf with Byte-Order-Mark which adds some control-charakters at the beginning of the file. In that case convert it to utf without BOM.

Comment: are you sure the content-type sent by the server along with that resource is `text/css`?

Comment: Please post a complete example that demonstrates the problem. The tag you have posted probably does not even contain the real relative URL. Also please specify whether this happens when testing locally on your computer (as the URL suggests) or when testing on a server (in which case the absolute URL of the document would be essential). Otherwise this remains an unsolved local mystery.

Comment: i check every thing mentioned here , simply its not worked

Comment: One more check to go: the character encoding of the css-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the number css files linking to document:
we are using this for testing UI and we seperate each UI in separate css file, then we aggregate it in one index file, the problem is in **Internet Explorer the maximum number of files linked to one document is 32!**

http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/the-32-external-css-files-limitation-of-internet-explorer-and-more/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ad1b6e88-bbfa-4cc4-9e95-3889b82a7c1d/